# Ionic 3 - ion-select not able to see values of select option

Tags: html, ionic3, html-select, angular6, ion-select

I am working on select option menus. I am not able to see values on drop down selection. I don't know what am I doing wrong. Please go through below code once

**1. HTML**

```
<ion-item id="fontBar" *ngIf="isAddTextSelected">
      <ion-label>Gender</ion-label>
      <ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
          <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee"></ion-option>
      </ion-select>
    </ion-item>
```

**2. JS**

```
this.employees = ["vishal", "poonam", "Asha", "Usha", "Sachin", "Rahul", "Mama", "Pravin", "Sehwag", "Rajendra", "Swara", "Ranu",
  "vishal", "poonam", "Asha", "Usha", "Sachin", "Rahul", "Mama", "Pravin", "Sehwag", "Rajendra", "Swara", "Ranu"];
```

*I have add values to employees variable in constructor.*

***Note -: I already imported below in app.module.ts and even added to required ts file.***

```
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp, {
      scrollPadding: false,
      [![scrollAssist][1]][1]: true,
      autoFocusAssist: false

}),
```

**3. Output-**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to give option an inner value, something like this:

```
<ion-option [value]="group.id">
  {{ group.name }}
</ion-option>
```

Answer (score 1):

The select component takes child ion-option components. If ion-option is not given a value attribute then it will use its text as the value.
So you can solve this problem in two ways:

1.Use value:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
 <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees" [value]="employee">
    {{employee}}
 </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

2.Without value:

```
<ion-select [(ngModel)]="gender">
 <ion-option *ngFor="let employee of employees">
    {{employee}}
 </ion-option>
</ion-select>
```

Reference:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/